# Обработка русских символов с клавиатуры wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

Написал код, при котором обрабатываются нажатия кнопок на клавиатуре, но если переключить раскладку на русскую, символы все равно записываются латинскими буквами, как сделать чтобы русские символы так же считывало при переключении раскладки

```
 DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        dt.Columns.Add("Key_Code", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("Key_Value", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("Key_State", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("Key_Char", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("System_Key", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("Key_Down", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("Key_Up", typeof(string));
    }

    private void KeyEvents(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {


        if (e.IsRepeat) return;
        string s = "" + e.Key; // key code
        string x = "" + e.SystemKey; // system key
        string z = "" + e.KeyStates; // key state
        string q = "" + e.IsUp; // key up
        string d = "" + e.IsDown; // key down
        string val = "" + (int)e.Key; // key value
        string ch = "" + (char)e.Key;// key char


        dt.Rows.Add(new string[] { s, val, z, ch, x, d, q });

        dg1.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
    }
```

Comment: А вы на какое событие подписываетесь?

Comment: key up, key down KeyDown="KeyEvents" KeyUp="KeyEvents"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если брать другое событие например TextInput, то можно перехватить русский символ, но у этого события нет свойств таких, какие есть у keydown и keyup